# Android: User information in all activities

Tags: android, facebook

after I have implemented facebook login, how do i ensure that all the activities in my application have the user information?

Many similar questions are using outdated sdk, hence i was wondering if there is any updated and more efficient method.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a good way to store data is using Shared Preferences:

This is how to store data:

```
    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    settings = getSharedPreferences("PreferencesFile", 0);
    editor = settings.edit();

    editor.putString("token", "yourToken");
    editor.commit();
```

This is how to retrieve data:

```
    getSharedPreferences("PreferencesFile", 0).getString("token", "errorMessage"));
```

Here is the tutorial about Shared Preferences given by Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Another good way of keeping data is using a design pattern called Singleton. Basically, it is a class that can be instantiated only once and is accessible from everywhere.

Here is a good tutorial about Singleton: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_singleton.htm